# How to "capture" the event when node moves under the stand still mouse

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

We know that in JavaFX the `MOUSE_MOVED` event is fired when the cursor moves on an `EventTarget`. In this case, the node stands still and the cursor moves.

Now, consider this: We have a `ScrollPane` and there are some small nodes in it. We let the cursor stay still, and scroll the wheel to scroll the pane. Then a node appears under the cursor. In this case, we will not get the `MOUSE_MOVED` event while the node passes under the cursor.

For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(20.0);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400); // Make the StackPane large enough
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();

        circle.setFill(Color.RED);
        circle.setLayoutX(200);
        circle.setLayoutY(200);
        canvas.setMouseTransparent(true);
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle, canvas);
        pane.setContent(root);

        circle.setOnMouseEntered(e -> System.out.println("entered"));
        circle.setOnMouseMoved(e -> System.out.println("moved"));
        circle.setOnMouseExited(e -> System.out.println("exited"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 420, 200);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

There is a `Circle` in a `ScrollPane`. If we let the cursor pass the circle, we will get

```
entered
moved
moved
...
exited
```

But if we posit the cursor in the width centre of the scene, above the circle, and use the wheel to scroll to let the circle pass the cursor. We will get

```
entered
exited
```

There are no `MOUSE_MOVED` events.

What I want is to find a type of event that could represent the missing part of the pass-through.

Comment: Did you try [onMouseEntered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseEnteredProperty)? Set that property on the `Node` that is in the `ScrollPane`.

Comment: @Abra They are two different events. I want to get the event (if there is that type of Event) when the pointer moves within the node relatively (the node moves, the pointer still).

Comment: `setOnMouseEntered` should work

Comment: hmm .. we get a mouseEntered/existed when the scrolling by wheel lets the cursor enter/exit the circle, we get a scroll event from the wheel: you might try to combine both, f.i. to get the location of the mouse relative to the circle as long as it is inside.